# How to convert text file into bitmap image in c?

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu

I want to convert a text file into a bitmap image.

As an example, suppose I have a text file named a.txt containing the string "Hello". I want use that to generate a "Hello.jpeg" (or any other bitmap format) containing an image of the string.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: http://libgd.bitbucket.org/

Answer (score 2):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/):

```
$ convert -size 2400x1200 xc:White \
    -gravity Center \
    -weight 700 -pointsize 200 \
    -annotate 0 "foo bar baz" \
    myText.png
```

There is a C API for ImageMagick that [you could leverage](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickAnnotateImage), or you could use [`system()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) to call the `convert` binary, as demonstrated above.